# When connecting to Pop3 server with Mailkit, connection fails every other time

Tags: ssl, pop3, mailkit

I'm trying to write some code to retrieve the e-mails stored in the `pop3` mailbox hosted at a third party email provider using `Mailkit (version 2.1.0.3)`. When attempting to connect to the mailserver, the connection fails every other time with the error:

> "An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS
>   connection."

With inner exception

> "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

So the code above on the first attempt succeeds, and on the second attempt fails with the error mentioned above. This happens without fail, and always fails the second time I try. This leads me to believe there is something wrong with terminating the connection.

Here is the code I use to set up a connection.

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client())
{
    await client.ConnectAsync("pop3.**.nl", 995, true); // FAILS HERE

    await client.AuthenticateAsync("**username**", "**password**");

    for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
    {
    ...
    }

    await client.DeleteAllMessagesAsync();
    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
}
```

I already attempting resolving the issue using the following functions, however, none of them helped. However changing the SSL protocol to version SSL3 and SSL2 caused the error to appear at every connection attempt, instead of every other one.

```
client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (e, r, t, y) => true;
client.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
```

Comment: Add a custom `client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` handler and figure out why the certificate validation is failing.

Comment: The callback is only called when the connection is succesful, not when it fails, so no errors are shown

Comment: I forgot to add an inner exception that: "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

Comment: The inner exception means that the server is rejecting your connection attempt. Are you making a lot of repeated connections? How long do you go between connections?

Comment: FWIW there is no v2.10.3 of MailKit. That said, the server is rejecting your connection. Are you making a lot of connections over a short period? How long do you wait between connections? Realistically, your question is unanswerable on StackOverflow because no one could possibly know why your server is rejecting the connection attempt.

Comment: You're right about the version, it's actually 2.1.0.3.
I'm connecting once per server request, so the error occurs when I attempt to connect again after 10 seconds or so.
I understand that it seems impossible to have an answer to this. I'm just wondering if there is something wrong with the code I've written. Maybe I forgot to close the connection properly. I'm at a bit of a loss, which is why I posted on SO. What is peculiar is that it actually works, but only when it attempted to connect once. The second time it connects, it always works.

Comment: Your code is fine, it even calls `Disconnect` with `true` so that everything disconnects cleanly, so that's good. Reconnecting within 10 seconds *might* be the issue, but it's impossible to say for sure. What if you only connect once every 10 minutes? Does that still have the issue on every 2nd connection attempt? I guess I'm wondering if you back off the re-connect time, maybe it won't happen anymore?

Comment: I've re-read what I wrote to describe the problem, and I'm concerned that my description was too vague. To be clear, the following happens:
1. Initial connect -> success
2. Connect again after 10 seconds -> fail
3. Connect again immediately after -> Success

Basically it seems the set up of the connection needs to fail once, before being able to succeed.

I'm not sure how long I have to wait before it works the first time, but I'm going to run some experiments today and tomorrow. I'm also going to contact the admin responsible for managing the mailbox.

Comment: FWIW, the inner exception you are getting suggests that the second connection is technically successful, but when the socket attempts to negotiate SSL/TLS, the server drops the client's connection.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that helps. I'll update this post with more information once I've delved deeper

Comment: I attempted connecting to the server using openssl, and there the exact same thing happens. First connection is succesful, but subsequent connection fails with the message that a secure connection is not supported. This for me proves that the problem lies at the server level, not my code.
Thank you for the advice and troubleshooting.

Comment: No problem, glad you’ve narrowed it down. I’m wondering what the admin might discover.

Comment: The admin got back to me and he told me that the server had some issues related to the pop-connector. He didn't go into detail unfortunately, but the issue is resolved for me. Thanks again for all the help!